# Loading child settings configuration settings into DI not loading list

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Here is the section in question from my appsettings.json

```
"AzureServiceBus": {
    "ConnectionString":  "XXXX",
    "Queues": {
      "Name": "DummyMessageQueue",
      "Pub" : true,
      "Sub" : true
    }
  },
```

The issue is that `_serviceBusConfiguration.Quotes` is always null. Its not loading the list.

## Program.cs

In my program.cs I load it as follows

```
// Register configuration options for the azure service bus in a options object. 
builder.Services.Configure<ServiceBusConfigurationOptions>(
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureServiceBus"));
```

I have tried adding GetChildren but this just results in compile error.

```
builder.Services.Configure<ServiceBusConfigurationOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureServiceBus").GetChildren<List<Queue>>());
```

Also didnt help

```
builder.Services.Configure<ServiceBusConfigurationOptions>(options => builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureServiceBus").Bind(options));
```

Also didnt work

```
var x = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureServiceBus");
x.GetChildren();
builder.Services.Configure<ServiceBusConfigurationOptions>(x);
```

## Di method

The constructor in my service then loads it as follows

```
public MessageReceiver(ILogger<MessageReceiver<T>> logger,
        IOptions<ServiceBusConfigurationOptions> serviceBusConfiguration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceBusConfiguration = serviceBusConfiguration.Value;

    }
```

The issue is that `_serviceBusConfiguration.Quotes` is always null. Its not loading the list.

## classes

```
public class ServiceBusConfigurationOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string QueueName { get; set; }
    public List<Queue> Queues { get; set; }
}

public class Queue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Sub { get; set; }
    public bool Pub { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configuration model:

```
public class ServiceBusConfigurationOptions
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string QueueName { get; set; }
    public List<Queue> Queues { get; set; }
}
```

Queues is a list, but in your appsetting.json, the "Queues" section is not array, this caused configuration binding failed. Try to change the "AzureServiceBus" section to:

```
"AzureServiceBus": {
    "ConnectionString":  "XXXX",
    "Queues": [{
      "Name": "DummyMessageQueue",
      "Pub" : true,
      "Sub" : true
    }]
  },
```